# jQuery - Close an already open toggle if clicked on

Tags: jquery

Had a look around on stackoverflow but can't see a similar problem.

I simply want to be able to close the open div that the toggles associated to. At the moment it just replays the toggle effect and slides it open, leaving a div always open/showing.

http://jsfiddle.net/Bx9Ya/

So if clicked, then open associated div. If clicked on again, slide associated div back up.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Like this? http://jsfiddle.net/Bx9Ya/4/
Hide all div's only when toggled element not visible ...

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that before you call toggle() on the one you care to show, you're explicitly hiding ALL of these DIVs with this line of your click function:

```
$('[class^=toggle-item]').hide();
```

If you've hidden all, toggling one means to open it.

Check this fiddle where I check the visible state then make a decision based on it: http://jsfiddle.net/JAAulde/Bx9Ya/6/

Comment: unrelated your use of classes is very very odd. Why bother if they're all going to be unique?

Comment: It's going into a CMS where they won't be unique, this is just for an example

Comment: I also added that line you quoted to make it only be able to have one open at a time, I appreciate it's not the best.